# Insert in Access Database via VB / Visual Studio (2017)

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access-2010

I´m trying to develop a system that reproduces a quiz game. Basically it´s developed with vb (vs 2017) and microsoft access database.
In certain point after the player choose the wrong answer, the system compiles the results with name, amount of righ questions and maximum score.
Aftewards it should record in the database the results., but, it doensnt make it.

My code follow bellow:

Sub RegistraJogo()

```
    Try
        Dim Conn As New OleDbConnection

        Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DbDesafioQuiz.accdb"
        Conn.Open()
        Dim cmd = Conn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TbRecordes (Nome, Data, Pontos, Acertadas) VALUES (@Jogador, @Datas, @Pts, @Corretas)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jogador", LbJogador.Text) 'nome do jogador
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datas", CStr(Now())) 'data do jogo
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pts", CStr(PontosTotais * QtdRespondidas)) 'variáveis com valores de pontos e qtd de questões resp
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Corretas", QtdRespondidas) 'qtd de questões respondidas
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    receivedData = 0

End Sub
```

Someone could help me, indicanting what i´m doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a calculated value should be inserted as text: `CStr(PontosTotais * QtdRespondidas))`. Neither a date value.

Comment: I changed that parameter, but returns the error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Incompatible data type in criteria expression on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: I only mentioned the obvious. Double-check the data types of all the fields.

Comment: I´ve changed the connection string, putting the complete adress of database. It´s working fine.
thanks @Gustav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve changed the connection string, putting the complete address of database, like:

"c:\temp\dbdesafioquiz.accdb"

Comment: Yes, the full path is normally needed.